# Cat Grooming Incident

Tags: michigan, pets

I recently took my cat to a groomer that advertises as being ‘cat only’ and even had a large sign on the front door that said ‘No Dogs’. When my girlfriend dropped my cat off she said there were two medium to large sized dogs that were barking very loudly and freely roaming the small building.

She did not feel very comfortable leaving the cat at the groomer but since we'd paid up front so ultimately decided to follow through. When I arrived to pick him up I had a similar experience, the dogs were running around freely and barking constantly.

The dogs belonged to the owner. They were making so much noise and acting so wild that she decided to let them out. She let them outside with no leash and within a minute they attacked a smaller dog that was being walked on the sidewalk. Her dog picked the smaller dog up, shook it, and threw it.

When she came back in, we confronted her about the situation. We came here so that our cat could be groomed in a less stressful environment and there were two untrained dogs wildly running around and barking. Dogs that clearly demonstrated on another dog what they would do to my cat if they had the chance. When confronted she got a little heated and said next time she would charge us double and that we were lucky she didn’t cut up our cat.

This was not the experience that I paid for, in addition this was not a controlled and safe environment for my pet. Is there a requirement to protect my pet in this situation? Is a cat grooming business that puts animals at risk even allowed to operate?

Comment: The only question in this somewhat rambling story is "What is my recourse here?", and we don't provide legal advice here.

Comment: The clear question is: is there any legal prohibition of such actions. This should not be closed as a request for legal advice.

Comment: My question is not asking for advice and should not be interpreted that way; Rather it is a question of whether the law prevents such actions from a business owner who is responsible for the care of a pet. Even more specifically I might ask whether this is an example of negligence on the part of the business owner or additionally whether the business owner has a legal obligation to provide a service as advertised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is no entry in the [Michigan state licensing list](https://www.michigan.gov/statelicensesearch/) for "cat groomers", there is one for "[dog groomers](https://www.michigan.gov/statelicensesearch/0,4671,7-180-24786-81056--,00.html)" which is probably indicative of licensing for "cat groomers" at the same time - basically, there is no state licensed required.  So theres no prospect of having one revoked.

So, what can you do?  Leave a bad review on Yelp, report them to the Better Business Bureau and never frequent the business again.

Or, if you so wish, you can invest time and effort into a lawsuit in an attempt to prove negligence, animal cruelty, animal endangerment or something else on the part of the groomers - but don't expect that to either be cheap or something you might definitely win.

Answer (score 4):

You personally have no recourse, but perhaps we can make this a bit more abstract and ask about legal recourse for anyone bringing their animal to a groomer. In general, if you take your animal to a groomer, they have a duty of care to you (the customer) with respect to your property, and if you are harmed (which would be the case if they damaged your animal), you can sue for compensation. If the animal had been killed their animal, that would be clear-cut. If it had been substantially injured, likewise. Possibly also if it had incurred a small puncture wound. There is also a class of dog liabilities where a human is injured because they are afraid of a dog, where a person had a reasonable fear of being attacked by a dog and hurt themselves trying to avoid the attack, but these would not be a good basis for a damage lawsuit in the case of a dog scaring a cat.

Comment: My primary concern is less ‘dog scaring cat’ and more business  owner created a situation where a tiny lapse in attention could have led to a dead pet (especially considering the exact situation that could have killed a cat happened while I was there).

Comment: @meowmeow And if that had happened, they would be liable. However, the law tends to focus on actual events rather than things that might happen.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and insight, @Studoku.

Comment: @meowmeow allowing people to sue for something that might have happened but didn't would be a terrible way to run a legal system.

Comment: Your comment is accurate. However at some level there should be protections in place to instill consumer confidence. A business should be required to provide services as advertised within reason and there are laws to that effect. Additionally, a business has some obligation to protect customer property in their care. Consider a vet that only works with gerbils for example. If that vet has a house cat that lives in the office, that would place unnecessary risk to the consumer and violate an essential expectation of the services provided.

Comment: Imagine a child’s only hair cutting service where the owner brings in their relative who has been convicted of being a pedophile, and that relative attacked a child on the property before. They knowingly brought in a predator that has actually attacked a customer on premises. The main difference that didn’t resonate until the answers here is that pets are effectively considered property under the law. However there are innumerable examples of the law being used as a preventative measure that punishes prior to a damage being incurred. I think the chosen answer nails the essence of the question.